# Ubuntu Clonezilla (Server) Disk Image Import/Export

Tags: ubuntu, export, import, clonezilla

We are running a clonezilla server(s) and I need to copy off (export) the newest disk image folder to and import it onto another clonezilla server in another city.

I found the directory in the ubuntu gui but it gives me permissions errors when copying the files; we tried doing it via command line and it couldn't see the drive (apparently it didn't mount correctly the second time, but I think that was in error...and something I can resolve...)
...either way I was wondering if someone had already figured out how to import and export clonezilla disk images from one server to another so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Please note that the server is on it's own switch and cannot be put on network, I have to copy to disk for a multitude of reasons.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10435/get-root-access-for-copying-files-to-usr-share -- you can just copy the directory out and then import it into /parting